# Windows Forms User Controls in WPF app

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls

Could someone post a link to simple tutorial, which describe how to use User Controls, created in Win Forms in WPF aplication's?
Thank's a lot.

Comment: You may want to reword your question as simply asking for links is not usually all that helpful.  If nothing else asking for simple tutorials that others have used themselves might get you better results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell:

1.Add a reference in your WPF project
    to `System.Windows.Forms` and
    `WindowsFormsIntegration`
2.Add the namespace in your XAML:

`xmlns:WinForms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"`

3.Use the WindowsFormsHost tag to surround any WinForms controls you use:

`<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <WinForms:DataGrid />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>`

4.Profit!